# How to clang-format this style of function definition

Tags: c, clang, clang-format

I would like to format my C code to a specific style of function definition like so:

foo.c (where "Arg" is a type/struct)

Example1:

```
void *
foo(
    const Arg *arg1 /**< my arg */
)
{
...
}
```

Example2

```
void *
foo(
    const Arg *arg1, /**< my arg */
    const Arg *arg2  /**< my arg2 */
)
{
...
}
```

1. Break after return type (AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType) - this works
2. Break after name of function+open parens
3. Each argument on a new line, indented
4. closing parens on new line, un-indented

I've tried many combinations of parameters without success... any tips?

Comment: What is `Arg`, why does your second example have two equally named parameters `arg1`, and what do you mean with "style of function declaration"?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly sensible question about how to use a tool to achieve a certain result, and tagged correctly.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker It's hard to understand it actually is. The important part of the question is in the title but not in the body. I voted to close as unclear at first and it took some time for me to retract it...

Comment: @StephanLechner, edited to add clarifications. Arg is just a type. By style I mean I want to format my code to match this specific code-style of function declarations. Let me know if that's clear.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Edited post to make it more clear, does that help? Let me know if it needs more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how to do it with `clang-format`, but `indent` can come pretty close:

```
indent -i4 -cd24 -blf -bfda file.c
```

(except for that closing paren--not sure how to do that).

Comment: Thanks for the reply